# How to unit test a Microsoft bot dialog with a prompt

Tags: c#, unit-testing, botframework

I'm using Microsofts Bot Framework and I'm trying to unit test (in isolation) a Dialog that I have:

```
public class MyDialog : IDialog
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        PromptDialog.Confirm(context, MessageReceived, "Are you sure?", "Sorry what was that?");
    }

    private async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> result)
    {
        bool isSure = await result;
        string response = isSure ? "Awesome" : "Sorry";
        IMessageActivity messageActivity = context.MakeMessage();
        messageActivity.Text = response;
        await context.PostAsync(messageActivity);
        context.Done<object>(null);
    }
}
```

I want to prove that if the IAwaitable result comes in as true, it replies with "Awesome" and if its false its "Sorry".

PromptDialog is a class with a static method [Confirm](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d9/d03/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_dialogs_1_1_prompt_dialog.html#a3e9963cd37505fe6cb68ea46acbd639e)

I have unit tested dialogs before successfully using moq to mock the IMessageActivity and IDialogContext that is passed into the dialog.  This feels more complicated because I want to mock a state of the dialog.

So Far:

```
    [TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    private Mock<IDialogContext> _dialogContext;
    private Mock<IMessageActivity> _messageActivity;
    private MyDialog _myDialog;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _dialogContext = new Mock<IDialogContext>();
        _messageActivity = new Mock<IMessageActivity>();
        _messageActivity.SetupAllProperties();
        _dialogContext.SetupSequence(x => x.MakeMessage())
            .Returns(_messageActivity.Object);

        _myDialog = new MyDialog();
    }

    [Test]
    public void GivenTrue_WhenIConfirmPrompt_ThenAwesome()
    {
        _myDialog
            .StartAsync(_dialogContext.Object)
            .Wait(CancellationToken.None);

        Assert.That(_messageActivity.Object.Text, Is.EqualTo("Awesome"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void GivenTrue_WhenIRejectPrompt_ThenSorry()
    {
        _myDialog
            .StartAsync(_dialogContext.Object)
            .Wait(CancellationToken.None);

        Assert.That(_messageActivity.Object.Text, Is.EqualTo("Sorry"));
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas how to do this?

Comment: What are you testing here? I see only mocks and no real objects

Comment: Sorry, added it to the test class

Comment: What is `PromptDialog.Confirm`? Is PromptDialog something static, can you mock it, ...?

Comment: Its a class with a static method on it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto testing for Microsoft Bot Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348791/auto-testing-for-microsoft-bot-framework)

Comment: Im wanting to unit test this class in isolation, not integration/system/fully test. @EzequielJadib can you please remove the possible duplicate tag?

Comment: The answer also contains links to unit tests... not only functional tests. The unit tests the bot framework team is doing. I didn't want to copy the same answer (without the functional tests links) here, but I can do that if you prefer to. See [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Tests/Microsoft.Bot.Sample.Tests/EchoBotTests.cs) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Tests/Microsoft.Bot.Sample.Tests)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good source to understand how to unit tests dialogs is the [Microsoft.Bot.Sample.Tests](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Tests/Microsoft.Bot.Sample.Tests) project from the [BotBuilder GitHub repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/).

There you will find the way the Bot Framework team is doing unit tests. The [EchoBotTests](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Tests/Microsoft.Bot.Sample.Tests/EchoBotTests.cs) are the easiest one to start with. It shows how to send a message to the bot and get the response to it, using a mocked connector factory.

The key is to inherit from [DialogTestBase](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Tests/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Tests/DialogTestBase.cs) which provides very useful helper methods.

Comment: @Ezequil Jalib : Is there a similar way for Node SDK?

Comment: I just replied to your questions with my knowledge around it.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the samples don´t seem to be kept in sync with the framework; currently the sample tests don´t work. Afte rversion 3.8 there have been breaking changes that prevent the base classes to compile.