# Setup UserData for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, botframework

How do i setup the UserData within the context for unit testing?

```
        var context = new Mock<IDialogContext>();
        context.Setup(c => c.Activity).Returns(() => new Activity());
        context.Setup(c => c.UserData).Returns(() => ?);
```

Should i use BotData?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unit test a Microsoft bot dialog with a prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925624/how-to-unit-test-a-microsoft-bot-dialog-with-a-prompt)

Comment: I could not find any test where UserData is set and tested. Am i missing it?

Answer (score 1):

Used the "DialogTestBase" class from BotBuilder tests and this worked for me.

```
        IBotDataBag dataBag;
        var container = Build(Options.LastWriteWinsCachingBotDataStore);
        var msg = MakeTestMessage();
        using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(container, msg))
        {
            var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
            await botData.LoadAsync(default(CancellationToken));
            dataBag = scope.Resolve<Func<IBotDataBag>>()();
        }

        var context = new Mock<IDialogContext>();
        context.Setup(c => c.UserData).Returns(() => dataBag);
        context.Object.UserData.SetValue(AppConstants.HelpType, helpType);
```