# How to Access User & Conversation Data in Test Functions for Bot Framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, botframework

I need to access user & conversation data while running unit tests.

In my bot code, I have implemented user & conversation data following the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp).

While running unit tests for my dialog, I cannot access to the save user data I updated during tests.

Below is my setup (from Virtual Assistant template `BotTestBase.cs`) for the bot test code.

```
var storage = new MemoryStorage();
Services.AddSingleton(new UserState(storage));
Services.AddSingleton(new ConversationState(storage));
Services.AddSingleton(sp =>
{
    var userState = sp.GetService<UserState>();
    var conversationState = sp.GetService<ConversationState>();
    return new BotStateSet(userState, conversationState);
});
```

Here is my test function:

```
userState = new UserState(new MemoryStorage());
var subDialog = new SubDialog(userState);
var MainDialog = new MainDialog(subDialog);
var testClient = new DialogTestClient(Channels.Msteams, MainDialog);

// some code here

reply = await testClient.SendActivityAsync<IMessageActivity>("Yes");
Assert.AreEqual("XXXX", ((HeroCard)reply.Attachments[0].Content).Text);

reply = await testClient.SendActivityAsync<IMessageActivity>("No");
Assert.AreEqual("OOOO", ((HeroCard)reply.Attachments[0].Content).Text);

reply = await testClient.SendActivityAsync<IMessageActivity>("Checkout");
Assert.AreEqual("XOXO", ((HeroCard)reply.Attachments[0].Content).Text);
```

Below is my user data in subDialog. I can update the data by `userProfile.xxxx = oooo`:

```
var userStateProfileAccessors = _userState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
var userProfile = await userStateProfileAccessors.GetAsync(dc.Context, () => new UserProfile());
```

The dialog would enter the subDialog after sending `Yes`, and user data get updated after sending `No`.

Right after I send `Checkout`, user data will be accessed to determine next step. But seems that user data did not get updated, I found null for all properties inside it.

> Does anyone know how to access user data for unit test in bot framework?

***Update***

I created the MRE. I did this by making a virtual assistant template, then I created a dialog CheckoutDialog.cs that assigns a value to my userProfile.DiscountStatus, and checks it in the next step. I created a test for this dialog CheckoutTests.cs, and when I debug the test I can see that my userProfile.DiscountStatus does not persist its state between steps. [Here](https://github.com/RayGunBJ4/botFrameWorkUnitTest) is the git repo.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is currently not enough information to reproduce the problem here.

Comment: Since there lacks enough information to properly help directly, the best I can suggest is to review the docs here [How to unit test bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/unit-test-bots?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

Comment: I am working on the minimal reproducible example. Will share later, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43244859/12217161

Comment: @MasLoo It doesn't work. I guess DialogtestBase is used with V3. My bot is developed with V4.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the below line above `var testClient = new DialogTestClient(Channels.Msteams, MainDialog);`

```
AutoSaveStateMiddleware autoSaveStateMiddleware = new AutoSaveStateMiddleware(userState);
```

Then changing that line to:

```
var testClient = new DialogTestClient(Channels.Msteams, MainDialog, middlewares: new List<IMiddleware>() { autoSaveStateMiddleware });
```

I created a simple repo with 2 projects & 3 classes to test this out:
[Repo with unit test of a dialog which saves & retrieves user state between 2 turns](https://github.com/silverbulletgt/bot-user-state-in-unit-test)

Looking at the code of DialogTestClient.cs (line 39) in [DialogTestClient.cs from Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Testing](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Testing/DialogTestClient.cs) the client implements AutoSaveStateMiddleware on the ConversationState only.

```
        public DialogTestClient(string channelId, Dialog targetDialog, object initialDialogOptions = null, IEnumerable<IMiddleware> middlewares = null, ConversationState conversationState = null)
    {
        ConversationState = conversationState ?? new ConversationState(new MemoryStorage());
        _testAdapter = new TestAdapter(channelId)
            .Use(new AutoSaveStateMiddleware(ConversationState));

        AddUserMiddlewares(middlewares);

        var dialogState = ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState");

        _callback = GetDefaultCallback(targetDialog, initialDialogOptions, dialogState);
    }
```

In your situation you are running the dialog only.  From what I have seen online saving of state to the storage provider is normally done in the Bot.OnTurnAsync method.  You don't have a bot in this case.  Adding AutoSaveStateMiddleware on UserState using the provided IMiddleware parameter will cause the UserState to save.  Then you should be able to read what you saved on future turns.

Comment: Hello, appreciate your answer. It works for me. Just have another question that I was working with "UserProfile" like this similar with what you did in your repo.
var userStateAccessors = _userState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
    var userProfile = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfile());
  How can I test it or have it setup in the DialogTestClient?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question.  It sounds like you are asking how to apply the AutoSaveStateMiddleware in your situation.  In your repo, https://github.com/RayGunBJ4/botFrameWorkUnitTest, it looks like you are asking about the test in "CheckoutTests.cs".  Add: AutoSaveStateMiddleware autoSaveStateMiddleware = new AutoSaveStateMiddleware(userState); before you instantiate the DialogTestClient, then instantiate the DialogTestClient like: var testClient = new DialogTestClient(Channels.Msteams, checkoutDialog, middlewares: new List<IMiddleware>() { autoSaveStateMiddleware });.

Comment: You will need to adjust your test though.  Where you have: Assert.AreEqual("No discount for you at this moment.", ((HeroCard)reply.Attachments[0].Content).Text);.  The result is actually not a HeroCard.  So change that line, plus the one in the other test to more like: Assert.AreEqual("You will receive a coupon shortly.", reply.Text);.  These 2 changes should cause your tests to pass.  Meaning the value of userProfile.DiscountStatus will be set to true / false based on the user's response to: "Do you have membership with us?"

Comment: My question that I would like to get data of "UserProfile" after I apply AutoSaveStateMiddleware in my test. Setting up AutoSaveStateMiddleware  is fine. But when my userProfile is basically nothing after this var userProfile = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfile())
So I am wondering that if there is a way to setup the userProfile while initiating AutoSaveStateMiddleware or userState?  Appreciate.