# Unit Testing Bot Framework Dialog with LUIS and Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, botframework

I'm trying to unit testing a method from my dialog, this method is called once the user says a keyword that is known by LUIS. Here the code flow,

"I want to reset my **password**", password is the entity that is linked to CustomerService intent.

```
    [LuisIntent("CustomerService")]
    public async Task customerServiceRequest(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        try
        {

            var entity = result.Entities.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == "ServiceKeyword" && customerSupportKeywords.Contains(c.Entity.ToLower()));

            if (!ReferenceEquals(entity, null))
            {
                switch (entity.Entity.ToLower())
                {
                    case "password":

                        PromptDialog.Choice(context, AfterUserHasChosenAsync, new string[] { "SMS", "Email" }, "¿How would you like reset your password?", attempts: 100);

                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

. When I select Email as a via to reset, the bot ask me to enter my email and this input is validated against a regex.

```
    private async Task AfterUserHasChosenAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        try
        {
            string userChoice = await result;

            switch (userChoice)
            {
                case "Email":
                    context.Call(AskForEmailToVerifyDialog(), AskForEmailToVerifyDialogStep1);
                    break;
                case "SMS":
                    context.Call(AskForCellNumberToVerifyDialog(), AskForCellNumberToVerifyDialogStep1);
                    break;
                default:
                    await context.PostAsync("Something was wrong");
                    context.Done(true);
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (TooManyAttemptsException)
        {
            await context.PostAsync(AnswerNotFoundMsg);
            context.Done(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

.

```
private IDialog<ContactMedioObject> AskForEmailToVerifyDialog()
    {
        try
        {

            return Chain.From(() => new PromptDialog.PromptString("Please enter your current email", "", 1).
            ContinueWith<string, ContactMedioObject>(async (context, result) =>
            {
                var email = await result;

                return Chain.Return(new ContactMedioObject() { Email = email });

            }));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

.

```
private async Task AskForEmailToVerifyDialogStep1(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<ContactMedioObject> result)
{
    try
    {
        var Cell = await result;

        if (!Cell.isValidEmail)
        {
            PromptDialog.Choice(context, OnResumeConfirmEmail, new string[] { "Yes", "No" }, "Would you like to try again?", attempts: 9999);
        }
        else
        {
                await context.PostAsync($".................");
                context.Done(true);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

I already unit tested customerServiceRequest following the same sintax from botbuilder repository https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/b6cd3ff85e8dc57ac586a11db489a0c75c635ae2/CSharp/Tests/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Tests/LuisTests.cs

But I cannot mock in the same way for AfterUserHasChosenAsync and AskForEmailToVerifyDialogStep1, Any idea how i can test these two method taking in account that AskForEmailToVerifyDialogStep1 returns a promptdialog if it is a bad email adress and a PostAsync if all was OK.?

Comment: Have you reviewed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42925624/how-to-unit-test-a-microsoft-bot-dialog-with-a-prompt?

Comment: thanks for reply Ezequiel, I was checking out EchoBotTests to test the whole flow, but the GetResponse method throws my an error, in the line await Conversation.SendAsync(scope, toBot); SendAsync receive as parameter a IMessageActivity and scope is ILifetimeScope type, im using the last version of Microsoft.Bot.Builder 3.8.2. Any suggestion?